# Android Studio build failed: Android resource linking failed, failed to create directory C:\tmp\

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I open the very first exercise project from Udacity Developing Android Apps course and it won't start - build fails with:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  W/ResourceType(10956): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
W/ResourceType(10956): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
W/ResourceType(10956): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
W/ResourceType(10956): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond type entryCount(1329)
error: failed to create directory 'C:\tmp\T01.01-Exercise-CreateLayout\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\example\android\favoritetoys'.

Command: C:\Users\anonymous\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\ab73a7122ce318e598c11600c6ce167a\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\tmp\T01.01-Exercise-CreateLayout\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\tmp\T01.01-Exercise-CreateLayout\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\tmp\T01.01-Exercise-CreateLayout\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\tmp\T01.01-Exercise-CreateLayout\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.android.favoritetoys\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\tmp\T01.01-Exercise-CreateLayout\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Reinstalling SDK doesn't help, neither Invalidate Caches / Restart option.

---

app version:
Android Studio 3.4.1
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 1, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to HasanElHefnawy's [comment](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/issues/427#issuecomment-444544844) from course github:

> This issue occurs after updating gradle version. In this case, the
>   following lines of code in build.gradle top-level project file must be
>   removed. They are only needed for the old gradle version.

So solution is just simply to **remove** these lines from **build.gradle** file:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (osName.contains("windows")) {
buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```